# Something to keep your eye on: Question Wizard

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

So the “Help new users ask better questions” Wizard has been in the works on SO for a long time.

[It has officially entered the testing phase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/2562182).

Worth keeping an eye on. If it works there, I’d imagine SE would want to roll it out to other sites as well, probably in order of traffic.

Which means in [6-8 time units](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/273503), we might be getting a little extra help here on EL&U keeping the garden tidy.

Notice how the first screenshot shows a selection of options for “what type of question”, including “software recommendations”, which are *off-topic* on SO, so they can be nipped in the bud. I imagine we could apply that here, to, say, proofreading requests.

Good stuff, I’m excited. One of the most prominent developments in the SE software I’ve seen in the last 2 years, honestly [aimed at improving question quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354125/2562182).

Comment: With respect to ELU, this is all purely speculation, right?

Comment: @Mitch Predictions are hard, especially about the future.